# Pending connections not being limited

Tags: reactor-netty

I am having a problem where an application is opening thousands of pending connections even though I have tried limiting the connections using the ConnectionProvider as shown below.

```
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = builder
    .maxConnections(50)
    .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(50))
    .pendingAcquireMaxCount(50)
    .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
    .evictInBackground(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
    .disposeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .build();
```

[Graph showing thousands of pending connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3pIv.png)

Am I doing something wrong that the number of pending connections are not being limited?

Comment: Please specify  your Reactor Netty version.

Comment: reactor-netty-core:1.0.17

Comment: Then please report an issue here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues
Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Link to [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/2261)